# Setting a global function in ionic Angullarjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the following code, and added the reset function that I would like to use from ng-click  at any place in any template.

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
  $ionicPlatform.reset = function(path) {
    console.log("hello")
  // $location.path( path );
  };
})
```

In index.html im trying to use it, but nothing happens.

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable nav-title-slide-ios7">
      <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon  ion-ios7-arrow-back">
        Back
      </ion-nav-back-button>
       <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        <button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="reset()">
          Refresh
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
```

Am I doing this wrong? Or how do you get a function available in all controllers?

Answer (score 1):

How about wrapping `ion-nav-bar` inside a div with a controller and using factory.

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services']);

app.factory('ResetService', function(){
    var reset = function(path){
      console.log('hello');
    };

    return reset;
});
```

Now you inject this factory in the controller you created controller. Good luck!